# Cannot fix last 2 vulnerabilities in npm audit. "npm audit fix --force" not helping

Tags: node.js, security, npm, npm-audit

I'm pretty stuck on how to fix this.

So my CI is not letting me checkin as a node package audit check comes back more than moderate our policy fails the build

```
audit-ci --moderate
```

Out of the blue today I got a bunch of high severity vulnerabilities.

41 vulnerabilities (9 moderate, 32 high)

So I run `npm audit fix` (see output here https://pastebin.com/J9MutM42). That changes my package-lock.json file, including changing

`"lockfileVersion": 1`

to

`"lockfileVersion": 2`

Not sure how bigger deal this is.

Unfortunately there are a bunch of potentially breaking changes so I run `npm audit fix --force` (and cross my fingers nothing is too hard). That gives this https://pastebin.com/1CefrTZv

So I guess that did something moving from

`41 vulnerabilities (9 moderate, 32 high)`

to

`9 vulnerabilities (7 moderate, 2 high)`

However why didn't it fix them all? Let's run it again... https://pastebin.com/9J8nxKfJ

Output looks a little different but still the name count of vulnerabilities:
`9 vulnerabilities (7 moderate, 2 high)`

Let's run it again ... https://pastebin.com/U5kw62rZ

**What!?** It increased the vulnerabilities:
`10 vulnerabilities (8 moderate, 2 high)`

Let's run it again ... https://pastebin.com/dfdphaQQ

Back to 9 vulnerabilities:
`9 vulnerabilities (7 moderate, 2 high)`

Running it again looks almost the same https://pastebin.com/8H6EBTfd. Running `npm audit fix --force` anymore just shows the same thing.

So how do I fix the 2 high vulnerabilities. I can't see any instructions on how to fix the last 2 high vulnerabilities.

Really stuck, thanks for the help :)